# Kaspersky anti-virus blocking file downloads

Tags: nginx

We have an issue where downloads from one of our websites fail intermittently and seem to be blocked by Kaspersky Anti Virus.

The behavior is different under each browser...for example firefox comes up saying that it can't be saved, because the source file could not be read and it's blocking the creation of the file in the local users temp directory.

Disabling Kaspersky fixes the issue fixes the issue but is far from ideal.  Is it possible to fix this server side?

The files arent being detected as viruses it's the writing to the users temp directory that seems to be intermittently blocked.

Thanks

More information:

The error that is being generated is

2015/09/07 15:24:18 [info] 26817#0: *28 client  closed keepalive connection (104: Connection reset by peer)

I've tried increasing my keep_alive timeouts but this doesn't seem to help  from 5 to 30 to 65.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this has anything to do with `keep-alive`. A `keep-alive` is merely for efficiency. i.e: it takes longer to set up a connection than to resume one; so instead of repeatedly dropping and rebuilding; send an innocuous packet between the client and server so that all parties agree that we're still "up". In the old-old days of ftp'ing source files from GNU, the keep-alive saved you from restarting your ftp and re-navigating to the correct directory.

It's ugly; but consider renaming the files to download with a non-executable suffix. If your anti-vir is blocking (and it sounds like it); you can sometimes end-run the filter by using an innocuous suffix (e.g. scaryfile.exe.jpeg).

It's also possible that you're suffering from a plain old time-out. I have watched anti-vir at an architectural firm (many designers use font-embedded PDF with multiple fonts so the files get huge) crush their e-mail because it took too long to run a signature check and the mail server simply timed-out waiting for a response. Consider a more nimble anti-vir. Consider configuring the anti-vir to trust downloads from your server's IP. Consider configuring the anti-vir to simply not filter ftp/http.